# Como eu dou um reset no servidor Flask usando if dentro do algorítimo?

Tags: python, api, flask

Seguinte, eu estou criando um jogo com o intuito de aprender, porém, eu preciso que esse jogo faça um "reset" quando a quantidade de tentativas for atingida. No inicio do código eu tenho o seguinte:

```
from random import randint
number = (randint(1, 100))
```

Ele gera o o valor aleatório para que o usuário tente o acertar. O usuário tem 10 chances de acertar, porém, no momento, após as 10 tentativas o jogo continua tendo como referência o mesmo valor "number"

Esse "jogo" roda no servidor flask com um front em HTML, gostaria de saber como eu faço para que chegando em 10 tentativas ele dê um "reset" no servidor, assim, gerando um numero novo para um novo jogo.

Segue o código do servidor:

```
#       // Function import for use make_response for cookies
from flask import Flask, make_response
#       //Function import request in directory static local server
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory
#       //Function that uploads files to the local server at http://localhost:5000/index.html
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static")
#       //Function to generate a random integer value in the variable number
from random import randint
number = (randint(1, 100))
print(number)
#       //Route function to receive the POST of the guess form
@app.route('/adivinhar', methods=['POST'])
def adivinhar():
#       //Reference number of html for variable N for comparison purposes   
    n = int(request.form.get('number'))
#       //Guard clause for cookie not defined    
    if  request.cookies.get('attemp'):
#       //Transform cookie string in interger for var a      
        a = request.cookies.get('attemp')
        a = int(a)
    else:
        a = 0
#       //the print(a) will shit if there is no cookie
#       //RETURN FOR LOSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando uma classe, se é a maneira mais adequada e a mais recomendável? Provavelmente não.

Geralmente APIs são construídas para serem stateless, ou seja, elas não guardam o "estado" das informações que passam por ela.

```
from flask import Flask
from random import randint

class Adivinhar:
      def __init__(self):
            self.number = (randint(1, 100))
            self.cont = 0

      def check(self, n):
            state = True if (str(self.number) == str(n)) else False
            self.number = (randint(5, 10)) if(self.cont >= 10) else self.number
            self.cont = 0 if(self.cont >= 10) else (self.cont + 1)
            return { 'num': self.number, 'cont': self.cont, 'acertou?': state}

adivinhar= Adivinhar()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/teste/<n>', methods=['GET'])
def teste(n):
      return str(adivinhar.check(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(debug=True)
```

**@Edit**

Não sei qual tipo de aplicação você está construindo, mas se for utilizar API, uma recomendação é a utilização da biblioteca *Flask-Restful* `(pip install Flask-Restful)`.

### resource.py

```
from flask_restful import Resource
class MyClass(Resource):
      def __init__(self):
            #do something...
            pass
      
      def get(self, *args):
            #do something...
            pass

      def post(self, *args):
            #do something
            pass
```

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from .resource import MyClass

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(MyClass, '/nome_da_rota_que_quero')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Se fizer um requisição GET para a rota '/nome_da_rota_que_quero', ele irá acessar o que está dentro do método/função GET, e assim para as outras requisições.

Comment: A idéia é não utilizar nenhuma aplicação e não utilizar JS, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

Um jogo depende muitas vezes de leitura do input do usuário e reage a elas de forma muito rápida. 
Dentro do desenvolvimento de jogos existe uma padrão que *resolve* esse problema chamado [game loop](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-game-loop-basix--active-8510) [[²]](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html). Um game loop é literalmente um loop feito com uma estrutura de repetição que só termina quando o usuário atinge seu objetivo.

O flask trabalha de maneira diferente. Ele trabalha em cima do feedback do usuário mas não de forma tão imperativa como um game loop faz.

O que te aconselho é implementar a estrutura de um gameloop em seu frontend e utilizar o flask apenas para *validar* se a o usuário esta ou não correto.

Você poderia criar essa estrutura com javascript puro fazendo requisições do tipo ajax para o flask ou optar por um framework voltado para esse tipo de coisa como o [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas).

Comment: Acho que você confundiu o nome da teoria, veja [Teoria dos Jogos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) não tem a ver com videogames.

Comment: Bem observado @AugustoVasques, confundi mesmo, ja editei minha resposta.

Comment: Olá, caros, obrigado pela explicação, irei tentar tomar outra abordagem, mas antes, vou tentar usar um direcionamento diferente da rota para reset de cookies e reset do ''NUMBER''. Irei pesquisar sobre o Canvas.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, eu consegui resolver o problema realizando um redirecionamento de rota, foi criado uma rota, quando o POST bate na "perdeu", ele me manda para uma outra página, nessa 
outra página eu zero os cookies e executo o random. Agradeço a ajuda. Segue o código:

```
# -- generating random number -- # 
from random import randint 
number = (randint(1, 100))
print(number)

# -- Defining "lost" route in POST -- #
@app.route('/perdeu', methods=['POST'])
def perdeu():
    number = (randint(1, 100))
    print(number)
    m = str(request.form.get('reset'))
    res = make_response(app.send_static_file('index.html'))
    res.set_cookie('attemp', '1')
    return res

# -- Defining "adivinhar" route in POST -- #
@app.route('/adivinhar', methods=['POST'])
def adivinhar():
# -- Reference number of html for variable N for comparison purposes -- #
```